# DRY approach for Django

Tags: python, django, dry

In my `urls.py` I have some Entries like these:

```
url(r'auftragsarten/list/$', generic.ListView.as_view(
        queryset=Auftragsart.objects.order_by('name'),
        paginate_by=25),
        name='auftragsarten_liste'),
url(r'^auftragsarten/form/$',
        views.auftragsarten_form,
        name='auftragsarten_form'),
url(r'auftragsarten/update/(?P<pk>[\d]+)/$',
    views.AuftragsartUpdateView.as_view(),
    name='auftragsarten_update'),
url(r'auftragsarten/delete/(?P<pk>[\d]+)/$',
    views.AuftragsartDeleteView.as_view(),
    name='auftragsarten_delete'),
```

This repeats for a lot of standard models where I just have to get the information, list it and be able to edit and delete it.

In my `views.py`:

```
def auftragsarten_form(request):

    form = AuftragsartenForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect('auftragsverwaltung:auftragsarten_liste')
    else:
        print(form.errors)

    return render(request, 'generic_form_template.html', {'form': form})


class AuftragsartUpdateView(UpdateView):

    model = Auftragsart
    fields = '__all__'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('auftragsverwaltung:auftragsarten_liste')
    template_name = 'generic_update_view.html'


class AuftragsartDeleteView(DeleteView):

    model = Auftragsart
    success_url = reverse_lazy('auftragsverwaltung:auftragsarten_liste')
    template_name = 'generic_confirm_delete.html'
```

It all repeats after this pattern. So for 3 models I will have 3 times mostly identical code with just minor changes.

How can I stop repeating myself?

Comment: I don't know, this looks pretty DRY to me. If it gets any drier it will be a drought :-)

Comment: I thought of maybe this three views but only changing the Model or something, well I could try to put it all in the urls.py, like the generic_list view but this seems like as DRY as I could make it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To turn it into a drought (to use @e4c5 words) you can do this in your `url.py` (this time with the `Mitarbeiter` Model)

```
url(r'^mitarbeiter/list/$', generic.ListView.as_view(
    queryset=Mitarbeiter.objects.order_by('name'),
    paginate_by=25),
    name='mitarbeiter_liste'),
url(r'^mitarbeiter/form/$',
    generic.CreateView.as_view(
        model=Mitarbeiter,
        fields='__all__',
        success_url=reverse_lazy('auftragsverwaltung:mitarbeiter_liste'),
        template_name='generic_form_template.html',
    ),
    name='mitarbeiter_form'),
url(r'^mitarbeiter/update/(?P<pk>[\d]+)/$',
    generic.UpdateView.as_view(
        model=Mitarbeiter,
        fields='__all__',
        success_url=reverse_lazy('auftragsverwaltung:mitarbeiter_liste'),
        template_name='generic_update_view.html',
    ),
    name='mitarbeiter_update'),
url(r'^mitarbeiter/delelte/(?P<pk>[\d]+)/$',
    generic.DeleteView.as_view(
        model=Mitarbeiter,
        success_url=reverse_lazy('auftragsverwaltung:mitarbeiter_liste'),
        template_name='generic_confirm_delete.html',
    ),
    name='mitarbeiter_delete'
    )
```

So I don't need a single view in my `views.py`. NB: there is no space for logic here just basic CRUD.

Answer (score 0):

urls:

```
url(r'^manage/list/(?P<model_name>.*)/$', MyCbv.as_view()),
```

views:

```
from django.db.models import get_model

class BaseBackendView(object):

    # Inherit this view so that your view will find the model name
    # You can reuse it for adding / editing / deleting etc for all models

    @property
    def model(self):
        return get_model('app_name', self.kwargs.get('model_name'))
```